# How to access instance variables?

Tags: python, class, variables, attributes

I recently stumbled upon a problem, How can I access a class's instance variables (i.e the variables inside `__init__` like `self.name`) from outside it's scope without creating an instance of that class (i.e `main = foo()`).

*Example of what I want to do:*

```py
class foo:
       def __init__(self,name):
           # wanna access self.name
           self.name = name
class bar:
    # And use it here
    os.mkdir(foo.name)
```

Comment: You can't. Also it's not clear why you're using nested classes at all.

Comment: jonrsharpe So is there a way to make a global variable that you can modify from outside the file?

Comment: Yes, with the `global` statement.

Comment: Just pass them as an argument to a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set the variable as `global`, and then you will be able to access this variable from everywhere. and also modifying it.

Not sure why you are using nested classes, but:

```py
foo_name = None
class main:
    class foo:
       def __init__(self,name):
           global foo_name
           foo_name = self.name = name
    class bar:
       def __init__(self):
           print(foo_name)


main.foo("Jonathan")
main.bar()
```

Prints out "Jonathan"